# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text' in beautifulsoop web-scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am doing a project using beautifulsoop(web scraping) in python. Earlier the program was running fine and perfectly. But, now it gives error as shown below. It might be that the html structure of the website would be changed. But still I am unable to figure out the error and solve it. Please help!!!

The website is - [https://covidindia.org/][1]

**Please help me to solve the error.**

**Error-**

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t1.py", line 112, in <module>
    mainLabel = tk.Label(root, text=get_corona_detail_of_india(), font=f, bg='light blue',fg='red')
  File "t1.py", line 23, in get_corona_detail_of_india
    total_cases = soup.find("div",class_="elementor-element elementor-element-aceece0 elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading",).get_text()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text
```

**My code-**

```
URL = 'https://covidindia.org/'
    page = requests.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    #print(soup)
    total_cases = soup.find("div",class_="elementor-element elementor-element-aceece0 elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading",).get_text()
    tc=(total_cases.strip())
```

**Also when I extract soup the o/p is-**

```
<html><head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr/><center>nginx</center>
```

**Is my access permanently forbidden??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `user-agent` header to your request. When u don't add a `user-agent`, then website detects you as a bot and hence doesn't give you access to the website's contents. Here is the full code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0'}

URL = 'https://covidindia.org/'

page = requests.get(URL,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

#print(soup)

total_cases = soup.find("div",class_="elementor-element elementor-element-aceece0 elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading",).get_text()

tc=(total_cases.strip())
```

Output:

```
>>> tc
'Total Cases - 83,14,673 (+46,171)'
```

Comment: headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0'}
The above line is for your Mac config. how should I do for my system? Please help me with that.

Comment: Use the same headers

Comment: Thanks!!! Now it shows this further, please help for this too--                                                              
    Code- URL = 'https://covidindia.org/'
    html_page = requests.get(URL).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'lxml')
    get_table=soup.find("table",id="tablepress-96")
    get_table_data=get_table.tbody.find_all("tr")                                                                                               error- 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tbody'

Comment: U have missed out the `headers` in ur code. Add them and it will work.

Comment: ohhh so I need to include them everywhere. Please review my question above again(the o/p of soup) why it shows "403 Forbidden"? So, can you please explain me why this was throwing error (previously the code worked fine) and why we used headers and how did it solved the error. As I am new to web-scraping, I don't know much about it. Also, thanks a lot for helping me!!! @Sushil

Comment: Added the explanation in my ans.

Comment: @Sushil I am requesting a server with a For loop with 3-6 sec gap, but its throwing the same error after 10-15 iterations. I added the header as per your advise but still same error.